# Server 2012 Connecting Multiple VPN Clients from Same Origin

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2012

We have an on-site windows 2012 server which has VPN access setup through the anywhere access. All works fine apart from if 2 people are trying to use the VPN that are in the same remote office as it only allows 1 person on at a time. If that user disconnects then the other can connect fine. I am assuming the VPN is looking the their external IP and thinking it is the same PC?

Is there a way to allow multiple connections from the same IP? I have been digging round for an answer but to no avail. Checked the RRAS menu and we can have up to 50 connections on the VPN. It only seems to be if a few people are in the same office as it allows people in different offices to connect simultaneously.

Comment: What protocol are you using? IPSEC has limitations - if there is any reason to still use PPTP that is one thing allowed, mostly beause most NAT routers can handle multiple PPTP connections.

Answer (score 0):

Although I use it on a daily basis, I do not consider myself a Microsoft expert. But if you're implementing a L2TP/IPSec VPN server and your clients are accessing it behind a NAT, its a protocol limitation. Instead, use IKEv2, OpenVPN or, if you can, deploy a site-to-site VPN in that specific client.

Comment: Thanks Stefano! We would have loved to have done site to site but as the offices the remote workers are in have other employees on the same network then we have to do it on specific clients. We will have a play around with IKEv2 and see how that goes and let you know.